# How do I edit an image on a Mac

Tags: macos, iphoto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best (cheap or free) image editing application for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/11111/best-cheap-or-free-image-editing-application-for-mac)

All I want to do is adjust an image to 72 x 72 pixels but there seems to be no built in programme to do it because in iPhoto when I try and crop it - it uses some other measurement because i set it as 72 x 72 but it stays huge when i export it

Comment: Come on man, you're making it look like I just copied the best answer!

Comment: Nah, I'm making it look like thelearner didn't look closely at the related questions before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Preview*, the default image viewer, will let you do that, in *Tools » Adjust Size…*

[image]

Comment: Tools > Adjust Size… will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more options than Preview has, you may want to try out:

- [the GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (open source image editor, tons of features), or
- [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html), the light weight version of the above.

Cheers!